# Svelte/Sapper: how to share a variable in context=module?

Tags: svelte, sapper

I have a */people/[slug]* route, and a series of other routes in the same folder:

*/people/[slug]/content*

*/people/[slug]/activity*

etc..

In the */people/[slug]* folder, I also have a *_layout* component where I am fetching a user object in the preload function (through server-side rendering).

Now I need a way for that user variable to be accessible to all other components in that folder.

That's easy to do if I only use client-side on these components.
I can use `setContext` in _layout, and `getContext` in all other components. Or I can use a store.

The problem is that I need to access this variable inside `<script context="module">`. And in there `getContext` doesn't work.

Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the remaining option is to use a store.

It should work in your `<script context="module">` just fine.

Given:

```html
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

export const foo = writable("foo");
```

You can:

```html
<script context="module">
    import { get } from 'svelte/store';
    import { foo } from './store.js';
    console.log("Foo was", get(foo)); // logs "foo"
    foo.set("A");
    console.log("Foo is", get(foo)); // logs "A"
</script>

<div>
    This is A. Foo is {$foo}
</div>
```

The Component renders as: `This is A. Foo is A`

Here's a more complete example:

https://svelte.dev/repl/d4f3e33d9bfb4fc2ac11e9d9a7a5f302?version=3.23.0

Comment: I should add that I can only verify that this works. I've no idea if it's proper :)

Comment: Thanks for the idea and example! The problem is that it doesn't work if we need to set/read the store from the preload function.